# Python with Selenium: Unable to find element to type in

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to find an element on website using Selenium but am having a hard time:

The page I'm looking at: https://corporate.axisbank.co.in/

The HTML from the selected element looks as follows:

```
<input name="FORM_CORPORATEID" type="text" onpaste="return false" ondrop="return false" ondrag="return false" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" autocomplete="off" id="corporateId" class="cm-input-box has-gradient-border">
```

I've tried using Id, XPath etc but keep getting errors:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
bankurl= "https://corporate.axisbank.co.in/"
driver.get(bankurl)
driver.find_element_by_name("FORM_CORPORATEID").send_keys("USERNAME")
```

I end up getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alwyn.kotze/PycharmProjects/AlwynAuto1/Automations/Axis1.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_name("FORM_CORPORATEID").send_keys("USERNAME")
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 489, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 957, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"FORM_CORPORATEID"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Are you able to find other elements in the page?

Comment: Nope, can't find any of them - but when I use the Selenium IDE, I'm able to select those elements and log in seamlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided to find the element and send the text **USERNAME** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  bankurl= "https://corporate.axisbank.co.in/"
  driver.get(bankurl)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#corporateId"))).send_keys("USERNAME")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: axis_bank]

Comment: Thank you so much! So I basically need for it to wait for the elements to load  before they can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
bankurl= "https://corporate.axisbank.co.in/"

driver.get(bankurl)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_id('corporateId').send_keys("USERNAME")
```